# Add type hinting to dynamic method call in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, python-typing

How to type method called dynamically ?

Example:

```py
class ABBase:
    def get_processor_func(self, name: str): # ?? How to type return ?
        func_name = f"process_{name}"
        return getattr(self, func_name, None)

    def process_all(self):
        for p in ['1', '2', '3']:
            func = self.get_processor_func(p)
            if func:
                print(func())

class ProcessA(ABBase):

    def process_1(self) -> int:
        return 111

    def process_2(self) -> int:
        return 222


class ProcessB(ABBase):

    def process_1(self) -> int:
        return 111

    def process_3(self) -> int:
        return 333


a = ProcessA()
a.process_all()
print('----')
b = ProcessB()
b.process_all()
```

Is this possible to add type annotation to this construction ?
How to type `get_processor_func` method or whole class ? Python 3.8 is enough for me.

Comment: Have you tried anything? The return type is either `None` or a callable?

Answer (score 3):

Since all the possible methods have the same type, you can specify that type statically.

```
from typing import Callable, Optional


class ABBase:
    def get_processor_func(self, name: str) -> Optional[Callable[[],int]]:
        func_name = f"process_{name}"
        return getattr(self, func_name, None)

    def process_all(self):
        for p in ['1', '2', '3']:
            func = self.get_processor_func(p)
            if func:
                print(func())
```

`Optional` accounts for the possibility that the return value is `None`, rather than an appropriate callable.

If the signature could vary, you can use `...` instead of a list of argument types: `Callable[...,int]`.

If the return type could vary, you can't do anything more useful than specify `typing.Any`.

In the worst case, where both the arguments and return type could vary, the best you can say is that `get_process_func` returns a callable.

```
def get_processor_func(self, name: str) -> Optional[Callable]
```

Comment: Ok thanks but I would like to do somethink like this:
`def get_processor_func(self, name: str) -> Optional["ABBase.process_{name}"]:` is that possible ?

Comment: No, because `ABBase.process...` is not a type, it's a name.